# What scope is required to access a YouTube channel title through an access token?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm working on a project which uses Google's PHP API Library. I am currently using the scopes with `offline` access:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`

But this did not give me access to get the channel title for the authenticated channel.

I then tried adding more scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit`

But I also had the same result. Is there a scope, that isn't related to YouTube that I am missing?

-

Here is the code that I am using, note that `$this->client` is an instance of `Google_Client`:

```
/**
 * Fetch channel title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function fetchChannelTitle() {

    /** @var \Google_Service_YouTube_Channel $details */
    $details = $this->getChannelDetails();
    $snippet = $details->getSnippet();

    return $snippet->getTitle();
}

/**
 * Get channel details
 *
 * @throws YouTubeException
 */
public function getChannelDetails()
{
    if (!$this->access_token) {
        throw new YouTubeException('NO_REFRESH_TOKEN');
    }

    $this->client->setAccessToken($this->access_token);

    $parts = 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics';
    $params = ['mine' => true];

    $response = (new Google_Service_YouTube($this->client))->channels->listChannels(
        $parts,
        $params
    );

    return $response->getItems()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to include this [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
```

and the field parameter '`title`' under `snippet`.

here's mine using the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&id=UCeZ6JFg58VsrnaioOEqgJgA&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=5&) :

```
"title": "Steve Jobs" //that's my title
```

Comment: I thought that the _force SSL_ scope is the same as the _just_ YouTube scope. I will look into this

Comment: include both scopes